# How to effectively compress photo to upload on iOS like Instagram?

Tags: ios, image, image-compression, uiimagejpegrepresentation

The original size of this photo is about 1.2M (2248 * 3264), took by iPhone5S.

[image: A Cat]

I tried using the `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and `image.drawInRect` method to resize (640 * 853) and compress the photo for upload.

- UIImageJPEGRepresentation 0.5 - 180KB
- UIImageJPEGRepresentation 0.9 - 524KB
- UIImageJPEGRepresentation 0.99 - 622KB

The file size is still too large, and the upload speed is not acceptable for me. (Need to upload about 200KB data). I also using PHP GD extension compressed more about 90% quality. The final size with `UIImageJPEGRepresentation 0.5` for me is (640 * 853) 100KB.

[image: My photo]

But I uploaded the same photo to Instagram, and download it from website. The file size is about (1080 * 1080) 86KB only. And their upload speed is fast.

[image: Instgram photo]

If Instagram app only upload 86KB data on photo, the photo upload speed is pleased.

It seems there are special ways to reduced the photo size on iOS, not just using `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`. Is there any open-source project or any different method to optimize with that?

Comment: My Apologies, can't figure out another way. Deleting answer.
Cheers!

Comment: @angolao did you figure out a good way to reduce image size without sacrificing much of the quality?

Comment: @MXV My way is compress the image as webp on phone, and convert as JPG on server.